# Replacing non zero values in a matrix with the marginals

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am trying to do some math with my matrix, i can write it down but i am not sure how to code it. This involves getting a column of row marginal values, then making a new matrix that has all non-zero row values replaced with the marginals, after that I would like to divide the sum of non zero new values to be the column marginals.

I can get to the row marginals but I cant seem to think of a way to repopulate.

example of what i want

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.matrix([[1,3,0],[0,1,2],[1,0,4]])

matrix([[1, 3, 0],
        [0, 1, 2],
        [1, 0, 4]])

marginals = ((matrix != 0).sum(1) / matrix.sum(1))

matrix([[0.5       ],
        [0.66666667],
        [0.4       ]])
```

What I want done next is a filling of the matrix based on the non zero locations of the first.

```
matrix([[0.5, 0.5, 0],
        [0, 0.667, 0.667],
        [0.4, 0, 0.4]])
```

Final wanted result is the new matrix column sum divided by the number of non zero occurrences in that column.

```
matrix([[(0.5+0.4)/2, (0.5+0.667)/2, (0.667+0.4)/2]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the final matrix we can use `matrix-multiplication` for efficiency -

```
In [84]: mask = matrix!=0

In [100]: (mask.T*marginals).T/mask.sum(0)
Out[100]: matrix([[0.45      , 0.58333334, 0.53333334]])
```

Or simpler -

```
In [110]: (marginals.T*mask)/mask.sum(0)
Out[110]: matrix([[0.45      , 0.58333334, 0.53333334]])
```

If you need that intermediate *filled* output too, use `np.multiply` for broadcasted elementwise multiplication  -

```
In [88]: np.multiply(mask,marginals)
Out[88]: 
matrix([[0.5       , 0.5       , 0.        ],
        [0.        , 0.66666667, 0.66666667],
        [0.4       , 0.        , 0.4       ]])
```